# Any plans of Monero based documentary?

Tags: education

I have seen the documentaries Rise and Rise of Bitcoins and Bitcoin Gospel, any plans of a documentary on Monero?

Answer (score 5):

I have not heard of one. But eventually, if Monero continues to grow and get mass adopted, a documentary is inevitable.

They'll have plenty of material to work with, considering our origins are as mysterious as Bitcoins. Yet we also have the whole CryptoNote/Bytecoin scam drama to add, alongside thankful_for_today's shenanigans, so it could be a colorful flick.

Personally I'm hoping for some silky narration by Fluffypony over HD coastal vistas of Plettenberg Bay.